# Python memory management when processing large images

Tags: python, image-processing, memory-management

I'm the maintainer of a package that implements a few [demosaicing algorithms for Python](https://github.com/colour-science/colour-demosaicing/) and a user reported excessive memory usage when processing 7K images. I came across issues like that when doing multi-processing although the solution was to use less concurrent processes in my case.

Here is, for example, the most offending definition, there are a lot of intermediate steps which are kept so that the code is not obfuscated and some are reused later too.

```python
def demosaicing_CFA_Bayer_Menon2007(CFA, pattern='RGGB', refining_step=True):
    CFA = np.asarray(CFA)
    R_m, G_m, B_m = masks_CFA_Bayer(CFA.shape, pattern)

    h_0 = np.array([0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0])
    h_1 = np.array([-0.25, 0, 0.5, 0, -0.25])

    R = CFA * R_m
    G = CFA * G_m
    B = CFA * B_m

    G_H = np.where(G_m == 0, _cnv_h(CFA, h_0) + _cnv_h(CFA, h_1), G)
    G_V = np.where(G_m == 0, _cnv_v(CFA, h_0) + _cnv_v(CFA, h_1), G)

    C_H = np.where(R_m == 1, R - G_H, 0)
    C_H = np.where(B_m == 1, B - G_H, C_H)

    C_V = np.where(R_m == 1, R - G_V, 0)
    C_V = np.where(B_m == 1, B - G_V, C_V)

    D_H = np.abs(C_H - np.pad(C_H, ((0, 0), (0, 2)),
                            mode=str('reflect'))[:, 2:])
    D_V = np.abs(C_V - np.pad(C_V, ((0, 2), (0, 0)),
                            mode=str('reflect'))[2:, :])

    k = np.array(
        [[0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 3, 0, 3],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]])  # yapf: disable

    d_H = convolve(D_H, k, mode='constant')
    d_V = convolve(D_V, np.transpose(k), mode='constant')

    mask = d_V >= d_H
    G = np.where(mask, G_H, G_V)
    M = np.where(mask, 1, 0)

    # Red rows.
    R_r = np.transpose(np.any(R_m == 1, axis=1)[np.newaxis]) * np.ones(R.shape)
    # Blue rows.
    B_r = np.transpose(np.any(B_m == 1, axis=1)[np.newaxis]) * np.ones(B.shape)

    k_b = np.array([0.5, 0, 0.5])

    R = np.where(
        np.logical_and(G_m == 1, R_r == 1),
        G + _cnv_h(R, k_b) - _cnv_h(G, k_b), R)

    R = np.where(
        np.logical_and(G_m == 1, B_r == 1) == 1,
        G + _cnv_v(R, k_b) - _cnv_v(G, k_b), R)

    B = np.where(
        np.logical_and(G_m == 1, B_r == 1),
        G + _cnv_h(B, k_b) - _cnv_h(G, k_b), B)

    B = np.where(
        np.logical_and(G_m == 1, R_r == 1) == 1,
        G + _cnv_v(B, k_b) - _cnv_v(G, k_b), B)

    R = np.where(
        np.logical_and(B_r == 1, B_m == 1),
        np.where(M == 1, B + _cnv_h(R, k_b) - _cnv_h(B, k_b),
                B + _cnv_v(R, k_b) - _cnv_v(B, k_b)), R)

    B = np.where(
        np.logical_and(R_r == 1, R_m == 1),
        np.where(M == 1, R + _cnv_h(B, k_b) - _cnv_h(R, k_b),
                R + _cnv_v(B, k_b) - _cnv_v(R, k_b)), B)

    RGB = tstack((R, G, B))

    if refining_step:
        RGB = refining_step_Menon2007(RGB, tstack((R_m, G_m, B_m)), M)

    return RGB
```

The user proposed a [PR](https://github.com/colour-science/colour-demosaicing/pull/10) where the intermediate steps variable are deleted as the process goes and garbage collection is forcibly requested. I never went down that road myself because I find that unelegant and when you start doing that it is hard to draw a line on where to stop. In any case, I would like that behavior to be opt-in also as forcing garbage collection might introduce other performance issues.

Given the above, I want to know if there are alternatives to not do that and if not if there is a way to write a function that would take care of deletion and garbage collection in one shot. The only bump I see is the deletion of the variables from their parent scope which is likely reachable through introspection.

Comment: I'm not sure garbage collection, if by that they mean the `gc` module, would be relevant here. You *should* consider the `numexpr` library here, though

Comment: The user was reporting cutting memory by a lot (potentially over 9go) in is use case by peppering the above definition with del and gc.collect statements.

Comment: Not creating intermediate variables I believe would help, however, the `gc` module only handles reference-cycles. CPython will deal with most objects using reference counting, and will *immediately* reclaim memory once reference counts go to zero. Maybe there are reference cycles, but it isn't obvious from this snippet

Comment: Is it acceptable to implement the algorithm in C++ and interface through Cython? If yes, then you can elegantly call delete with minimal performance overhead within C++...

Comment: @mahesh that might be a pain for portability. Right now this is a pure python library. But then... I was playing around with Rust bindings fur Python recently....